# simple_form multiple inputs inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using simple_form 1.5.2 + rails 3.1 gem in my project, but simple_form generates one input per line.

How to do to have more of one inputs per line?

Comment: Hi, Can you give an example of how you'd like your form to look?  What code are you using now? (Code examples always help clarify a question)

Comment: I wanted a form with two columns, but I solved. Thank you guy.

Comment: Can you show what your css looked like? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: tried a :style => "float: left !important;" but that still sets the elements below each other on a newline

Comment: Look this http://www.elated.com/articles/css-floats/ 
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem using `:wrapper_html => { :class => "myclass" }`

Answer (score 4):

I did this:

```
:wrapper_html => { :style => 'display: inline' }
```